# Google Analytics export: Ads data in a continuous export

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have my Google Analytics Premium account linked to BigQuery - it currently uploads data once a day, I'd like to change this to continuous, but I note the message that says 'does not contain Ads Data' - does anyone know exactly which ads data this includes, and whether this will be appended later, or never included?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as you, then I realised, it says "Select *current day* streaming preferences" which gives you the hint, with Google, the devil is in the details!